# How can I keep PHP session alive with AJAX in native JS?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My HTML file calls functions on the JS file which pass parameters to the PHP file to call specific functions. My problem is that I would like the PHP session to stay alive so that when the user calls the login function, the $connection variable stays alive and can be used when the user eventually calls the loadBD function and Ajax calls the PHP file, the $connection variable is empty. I know I could use a file with the login details and include it at the start of the PHP file, but that won't work, because I don't know the details yet. How can I only login once?

Here is the JS file:

```
function runScript(params) {
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'scripts.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
    else {
        alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
    }
};
xhr.send(encodeURI(params));
}

function login() {
  var params = "func=login";
  params += "&svr=" + document.getElementById('srv').value;
    params += "&name=" + document.getElementById('name').value;
    params += "&psw=" + document.getElementById('psw').value;
    ;
    runScript(params);
}

function loadBD() {
  var params = "func=load_db";
    runScript(params);
}
```

Here is my PHP file:

```
<?php

$func = $_POST["func"];
$connection;

switch ($func) {
    case 'login': 
        login();
        break;
    case 'load_db': 
        load_db();
        break;
    default: echo 'Function Error'; 
    break;
}

function login() {
    $connection = @mysqli_connect($_POST["svr"], $_POST["name"], $_POST["psw"]) or die("initial host/db connection problem");
    if(errorCheck($connection)) {
        getDatabases($connection);
    }
}

function errorCheck($connection) {
    if (!$connection) {
        echo "internal error " . mysqli_errno();
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}

function getDatabases($connection) {
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SHOW DATABASES");
    $available = array();
    $index = 0;

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row( $result ) ){
        if (($row[0]!="information_schema") && ($row[0]!="mysql")) {
            echo $row[0];
            $available[$index] = $row[0];
            $index += 1;
            echo "<a href='javascript:loadDB();' >Load $row[0]</a>";
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}

function load_db() {
    echo "loading";
    echo $connection;
}

?>
```

Comment: The connection variable doesn't have to do with the session being alive or not. (1) PHP variables are only in scope for the duration of a request. (2) Even if you do store the variable in the `$_SESSION` superglobal, a database connection is closed when the request is done unless you are using a [persistent connection](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php) which is another thing completely.

Comment: So would recommend that the login function on the PHP file be call every time? If so, how can I store the login details for reuse?

Comment: What typically happens is the user sends the sign in information to the server only once. You check it on the server, and if it is valid, you store a variable in [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) which says that "this user has signed in". The `$_SESSION` super global has information regarding the specific user only so it's safe (most of the time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't keep the connection open between requests; that's not really how PHP works (by default, anyway). What you could do is store the connection details for the user session in PHP's [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) and use that to reestablish the connection to the database when the user hits your PHP script.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and report back

Answer (score 3):

This is extremely insecure and a very bad idea.  You are exposing your database credentials to the world on your web page.  Standard practice is to store your database configuration in a secure location on your server and reference that config file directly from PHP.

Keeping database connections alive between requests is separate from PHP sessions.  It depends very much on the details of your setup, so see the [official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php) for details.

PHP sessions themselves are "alive" in the sense they are tracked across requests via the session cookie.  As long as the same cookie exists and the session hasn't [expired](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php), you do not need to do anything extra to keep it "alive".

Comment: I'm a bit overwhelmed by the shear amount of ways people say to store data in a file via PHP. So, assuming the file was in a safe location, would using Json be suitable?

Comment: Yes, common file formats for configurations include INI, YAML, and JSON.